# Using a custom query to select items where their id exists within a list of IDs

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper, ormlite-servicestack

In dapper you can do something like:

```
var items = connection.Query<Items>("SELECT * FROM `@database`.`table`  WHERE `id` IN @idList;", new {database = DatabaseName, idList = someList.Select(n => n.id)});
```

trying to do the same in ormlite:

```
var items = connection.Query<Items>("SELECT * FROM {0}`.`table`  WHERE `id` IN {1};", DatabaseName, someList.Select(n => n.id)});
```

returns an error. Dapper creates the query as such:

```
SELECT * FROM `someDB`.`table` WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3,4);
```

where ormlite generates:

```
SELECT * FROM `someDB`.`table` WHERE `id` IN [1,2,3,4];
```

The square brackets aren't valid in MySQL. Is it possible to do this in ormlite?

When I try using the anonymous class to list parameters, as in the dapper example, it can't find the second parameter.

Comment: Actually, dapper creates the query as `IN (@idList0, @idList1, @idList2)` ... just sayin' ;) But this sounds like a question for @Mythz...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do a **SQL IN** statement, OrmLite needs to be able to escape all the values when it needs to (i.e. if they're string values). So if using raw SQL in OrmLite you can do:

```
var ids = someList.Select(n => n.id).ToArray();

var items = db.Select<Items>(
    "SELECT * FROM `{0}`.`table`  WHERE `id` IN ({1})", 
    DatabaseName, new SqlInValues(ids));
```

Although most of the time you don't need to use Raw SQL in OrmLite, it's more succinct and portable if you instead use the typed API. e.g:

```
var items = db.Select<Items>(q => Sql.In(q.Id, ids));
```

You can also use `[Alias]` if your table wasn't the same name as the POCO, and can also specify the `[Schema]` with:

```
[Schema("DatabaseName")]
[Alias("table")]
public class Items 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which will instead use the specified Schema and table name when querying the db.

Comment: Hi mythz, I rewrote the code and am now using the typed API. I did experience an issue though using the "Sql.In" statement. It would still put the square brackets around an int collection. If I converted the collection to <string> first, the issue didn't occur. Is this the expected behaviour, or an issue with using MySQL?

Comment: hmmm, must be a bug. Can you [post an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki) with a small snippet that shows the repro so we can track it?